# Left-filling a text field with zeros

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a postgres database that I can access with PGAdmin III. I run a script to change a number stored in a text field and then add left zeros to file it to four characters. It's a time field that must be stored as text. I'd like to do it in a single run instead of two. Here's the first clause to add hours to the time field as text;

```
UPDATE timetable
SET eta = (
  CASE 
    WHEN (trips.starttime::int / 100) + (destination.zuluoffset * -1 ) < 24 THEN ((trips.starttime::int / 100) + (destination.zuluoffset * -1 )) * 100
    WHEN (trips.starttime::int / 100) + (destination.zuluoffset * -1 ) > 23 THEN ((trips.starttime::int / 100) + (destination.zuluoffset * -1 ) - 24) * 100
  END )
FROM  
  destination, 
  trips
WHERE 
  timetable.tripsid = trips.id;
```

This does fine and adds the desired number of hours while correcting for results of greater than 24 hours. However, this leave any times less than 1000 hours as three digits or even a single 0 for midnight. The field needs to be 4 characters.

So I run this as a second clause;

```
UPDATE timetable
SET eta = lpad(eta, 4, '0');
```

and this works also. But how can I add the lpad to the first Update clause? I tried putting the entire CASE statement in the lpad statement in place of eta like this;

```
SET eta = lpad((CASE statement here), 4, '0')
```

but I get this error;

```
ERROR:  function lpad(numeric, integer, unknown) does not exist
LINE 3: SET eta = lpad((
                  ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I've tried casting eta with ::int, ::text, and ::varchar, but that just return a sytax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using LPAD if the result of your CASE statement is numeric , use simply to_char :

```
 UPDATE timetable
          SET eta = to_char (
               CASE 
                 WHEN (trips.starttime::int / 100) + (destination.zuluoffset * -1 ) < 24 THEN ((trips.starttime::int / 100) + (destination.zuluoffset * -1 )) * 100
                WHEN (trips.starttime::int / 100) + (destination.zuluoffset * -1 ) > 23 THEN ((trips.starttime::int / 100) + (destination.zuluoffset * -1 ) - 24) * 100
            END , 'FM0000')
FROM  destination
INNER JOIN trips ON timetable.tripsid = trips.id;
```

Comment: This worked as well as the one above. I selected this one because it seemed "more" correct in that it uses char formatting directly instead of converting num to char. Thanks for the excellent reply.

Answer (score 2):

should be   `LPAD(your_col::text, 4, '0')`

```
    UPDATE timetable
    SET eta = LPAD ((
      CASE 
        WHEN (trips.starttime::int / 100) + (destination.zuluoffset * -1 ) < 24 THEN ((trips.starttime::int / 100) + (destination.zuluoffset * -1 )) * 100
        WHEN (trips.starttime::int / 100) + (destination.zuluoffset * -1 ) > 23 THEN ((trips.starttime::int / 100) + (destination.zuluoffset * -1 ) - 24) * 100
      END )::text, 4,'0')
    FROM  destination
    INNER JOIN trips ON timetable.tripsid = trips.id;
```

Comment: This worked as well as the one below. However, I can only select one "correct" reply. Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: @StuartK.Smith  at least you could  rate as  usefull  .. (upper  arrow)

Comment: Thanks again - new to Stack Overflow. Done. :)